# Problems when using realloc() in a function to resize the int pointer

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I want to make a `int*` with size of 10 first and write a `add()` function to add elements. If the numbers of elements are bigger than 10, the function will use `realloc()` to resize the `int*`. However I got the error message. How can I improve this?

Here is what I did:

```
int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    int* a;
    a = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
    int i;
    double start, stop;
    start = clock();

    for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        add(&a, i, size, i);
    }

    stop = clock();
    printf("Adding arry by one: %10.2f\n", stop - start);

    return 0;
}


void add(int *a, int element, int size, int index)
{
    if (index < size)
    {
        a[index] = element;
    }
    else if (index >= size)
    {
        a = realloc(a, sizeof(int*)*(index + 1));
        a[index] = element;
    }
}
```

Comment: `void add(int*a,` --> `void add(int **a,`, `*a = realloc(*a, sizeof(int)*(index + 1));` , (need update size?)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Although unusual, the `realloc` is done on `index` (which does get upped) and not `size` (which is fixed), so it's "okay" [if not optimal]

Comment: You can't make an `int*` with a size of 10.  You can, however, make an `int*` point to a memory block with a size of 10 ints.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried to modify it as what you said, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In two places, you should have `sizeof(int)` and not `sizeof(int*)`. `a` is an array of `int`, not an array of *pointers to `int`s*.

Comment: @Allen [example might not what you desire](http://ideone.com/xzKxmw)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY wow that's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pointer a is a parameter of the function add. Parameters are just local variables in that function, so when you assign a = realloc (...) the a in the calling function isn't changed. This will crash rather quickly. size is also not adjusted - if you added an element at index 17, then index 12, your array would be resized to 13 elements.

You can use BLUEPIXY's solution. I'd prefer creating a struct containing a pointer and a size, and passing that around and letting code update it. Avoids to many **s; they are not good for your brain :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the int * a parameter to int ** a. I have made some changes on the structure:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 10

void add(int**a, int element, int size, int index) {
  if (index >= size) {
    *a = realloc(*a, sizeof(int)*(index + 1));
  }
  (*a)[index] = element;
}

int main() {
  int *a = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(int));
  double start, stop;

  start = clock();

  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    add(&a, i, SIZE, i);
  }

  stop = clock();

  printf("Adding arry by one: %10.2f\n", stop - start);

  free(a);

  return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Malloc and realloc should be done for size of(int) not for size of(int*)